# Knockout - Unable to process binding, gridViewModel is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I am new to knockout and I have no idea why I am getting this message.

Unable to process binding "simpleGrid: function (){return gridViewModel }"
Message: gridViewModel is not defined;

**library_customization.js**

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
var title = 'Library Customization';
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: title
};

return vm;


var initialData = [
{ name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
{ name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
{ name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
{ name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
{ name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
{ name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
{ name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

var PagedGridModel = function (items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.addItem = function () {
        this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
    };

    this.sortByName = function () {
        this.items.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
        });
    };

    this.jumpToFirstPage = function () {
        this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
    };

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
            { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
        ],
        pageSize: 4
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));

function activate() {
    logger.log(title + ' selected', null, title, true);
    return true;
}

});
```

**library_customization.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="libraryCust">
    <head>

    <title> Project</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>
    </section>


    <div class='liveExample'>

        <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'></div>
        <!--  -->
        <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
            Add item
        </button>

        <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
            Sort by name
        </button>

        <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
            Jump to first page
        </button>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/qsgzhxj7/)

I think the main problem is that you exit your module earlier than planned in the code below:

```
var title = 'Library Customization';
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: title
};

return vm;

/* your main code follows below but never executes */
```

So I moved these properties into the PagedGridModel constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I write things like that in my project I still get this error message: **Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/library_customization). Details: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.** Could you tell my why, or at least where I should look for the errors?

Comment: @kata You apparently have multiple calls to `ko.applyBindings`. That is usually a bad idea, but if you're going to do it, you need to constrain each call to a DOM element by passing a second argument.

Comment: If you need multiple ko models working simultaneously you have to specify elements to bind to like:  `ko.applyBindings( yourViewModel, document.getElementById( elementId ) )`. Or if you have one viewmodel as Roy said you probably called `ko.applyBindings` on same element or whole document several times. Check places where you call `ko.applyBindings` to make sure they not overlap.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, everything is working now.:)